# Python way to replace a substring from a tuple of substrings with appropriate pair from another tuple

Tags: python

I am looking for a fast solution where the code should loop over a very long list of sentences (per line) and replace a substring from one tuple (or list) with a match from another tuple. The (pseudo) code should look like this:

```
# an example of one line sentence:
a = "I was thinking to begin this journey."

# tuples: targets and replacements
verbs = ("to begin", "I begin", "you begin", "we begin")
verbs_fixed = ("toXXbegin", "IXXbegin", "youXXbegin", "weXXbegin")

with open(<INPUT FILE NAME>) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        line = ????
```

Given that list of sentences is quite long, I would appreciate the fastest solution.

I was thinking about `re.compile` and then some list comprehension. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you add the output?

Comment: Is it always `wordXXword`? Would it be possible to just replace space with XX ?

Comment: just zip them and replace, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @SimonFink well, it's obviously a tuple, but actually she wanted to say "list"

Comment: @BUFU, no it's definitely a "tuple".

Comment: @Austin Why? Does it need to be immutable to work? It could well be two lists.. Lists even make more sense to me given that you could append to both lists instead of creating new tuples each time you want to modify your "dictionary". And a dictionary might actually even be the best solution. Am I completely wrong here? What do I miss?

Comment: @BUFU, I was talking about what *"actually she wanted to say"* part of your comment. She definitely wanted to say "tuple" and I suppose you know I was not proposing a solution.

Comment: @Austin Oh yeah, you're completely right then. "Tuple" was of course intended. I was just using that phrase as a figure of speech to suggest that lists might be more useful. But actually in the OP example they are tuples and it makes sense without further context. Sorry to be so unclear. I sometimes forget to check my words....

Answer (score 1):

If you zip your two lists, then you have just simple replaces:

```
for original_value, target_value in zip(verbs, verbs_fixed):
    line = line.replace(original_value, target_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using regex**

```
def regex_mapping(sentence):
    " Function to do the replacements based upon mapping of verbs to verbs fixed"
    return  regex_pattern.sub(lambda m: mapping[m.group(0)], sentence)


# Setup code
verbs = ("to begin", "I begin", "you begin", "we begin")
verbs_fixed = ("toXXbegin", "IXXbegin", "youXXbegin", "weXXbegin")

# Dictionary mapping
mapping = {x:y for x, y in zip(verbs, verbs_fixed)}

# Regex pattern (pre-compile for speed)
regex_pattern = re.compile('|'.join(verbs))
```

**Usage**

```
a = "I was thinking to begin this journey."

print(regex_mapping(a))
```

**Addendum**

If your list of keywords is in the hundreds you should look into this [solution](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/regex-was-taking-5-days-flashtext-does-it-in-15-minutes-55f04411025f/) which is based upon building a Trie dictionary.